# Check if program is installed if so go to next powershell

Tags: powershell

I've googled and not found anything useful to me.

I have 4 msi files I want to install but would like to check if some of it is installed on the computer.

Example:
check if program 1 is installed, if not install it and go to and install program 2. 
However if it's not installed, install it and go to program 2 and do the same test there.

```
Execute-MSI -Action Install -Path "$dirFiles\Program1"
Execute-MSI -Action Install -Path "$dirFiles\Program2"
Execute-MSI -Action Install -Path "$dirFiles\Program3"
Execute-MSI -Action Install -Path "$dirFiles\Program4"
```

Comment: Hi, have you written _any_ code yet? We need to see it to help you. You can [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42228400/edit) to include it.

Comment: I've done that. How do I implement the check to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the GUID, you could test path the [uninstall key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372105(v=vs.85).aspx). Also don't forget that if your OS is 64 bit, there will be the same key in `WOW6432Node` for 32 bit apps.

```
$uninstallkey = "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"
$uninstall32key = "HKLM:\Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"
#Example 64-bit app
$app1guid = "{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}"
if (!(Test-Path "$uninstallkey\$app1guid)) {Execute-MSI -Action Install -Path "$dirFiles\Program1"}
#Example 32-bit app
$app2guid = "{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}"
if (!(Test-Path "$uninstall32key\$app2guid)) {Execute-MSI -Action Install -Path "$dirFiles\Program1"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about your applications, there are two easy options I can think of.

1) Read a log file, looking for a pattern / string - check 6 times (configure as needed) and fail if it doesn't complete. If it does, move on to the next install and do the same check

```
       $LOGFILE =  'C:\Somewhere.log'
   $Complete = 'no'
   $Counter = 1
   $max = 6

 Start-Sleep 10

    DO {

    $Check =  SELECT-STRING -pattern 'status: 0.' -path $logfile -quiet
    write-host $Check
     If (($Check) -eq $True)  {
   Set-Variable -name Complete -Value "yes"
        } 
            Else {Set-Variable -name Complete -Value 'no'} 
                 Write-host $Counter
                 Start-Sleep 20
                 $Counter++
                          }

             while ($Complete -eq 'no') 

              If (($Counter) -eq $max)  {

  Throw 'Installation failed, check the error log'

        }
```

Option 2)

If you know what directories it creates or even a file count, can do something like the above with count instead of a file read

```
    $PRDIR = "D:\Folder"
    If (($PRDIR.Count) -gt 2)
    {
Do something
}
Else
{
Do something else
{
```

Hope that helps!

R

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WMI` to check if your MSIs are installed or not. Example:

```
$products = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_product |  Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*someName*" } | Select-Object *
```

You might extend the `Where-Object` clause with additional patterns to query for (e.g. via `$_.Name -like "*Sw1*" -or $_.Name -like "*Sw2*"` ). `$products` should be an array including the findings, which you can use to check if the requested SW is installed or not. Example:

```
PS> $found = $results.Where({ $_.Name -like "*sw1*"}) 
PS> if ($found) { Write-Host "Found" }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Be careful with `Win32_Product`, every time it is called it runs a repair on all MSIs. So at the very least it is generally really slow.