# List windows applications and paths

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

I would like to know whether it is possible to get a list (as a text file) of all applications installed on my PC, and their locations.

For example, I have Google Chrome installed on my computer. I would like this to show up as:

```
Google Chrome
C:\Program Files\...(path)...\chrome.exe
```

Or something along those lines.
I have seen programs in powershell and other languages which, using the registry, find one or the other, but not both. How (and in what language) might this be possible?

Edit: The main problem here is that the registry keys for App Paths and Uninstall (where I might find the names) is that their keys have completely different names. But it is presumably possible, as the 'Change or Remove a Program' utility contains both. Is there a way to programatically convert this to a text file?

Comment: You probably have not seen it because there is not a direct correlation anywhere between the list of installed programs and the main executable files for those programs. You might figure out a way to, say, get all executables for a given entry in Programs and Features, but many programs come with multiple executables. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if program is installed if so go to next powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228400/check-if-program-is-installed-if-so-go-to-next-powershell)

Comment: In particular you would be looking likely looking for InstallLocation value, in the Uninstall Keys.

Comment: Isn't this essentially what you want? https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/11/13/use-powershell-to-quickly-find-installed-software/  I ran it locally and a majority of the locations show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found an answer of my own, using Batch code. I was wondering how Cortana is so quickly able to search through installed programs and their names, when I realised that the start menu entries are used. The piece of code below finds the names and locations of installed program shortcuts (excluding uninstallers):

```
@echo off
break > names.txt
break > locations.txt
set "curpath=%cd%"
cd "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu"
FOR /R %%G IN ("*.lnk") DO (
    echo "%%~nG" |findstr /i "install">nul || (
        echo %%~nG >> "%curpath%/names.txt"
        echo %%G >> "%curpath%/locations.txt"
    )
)
cd "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"
FOR /R %%G IN ("*.lnk") DO (
    echo "%%~nG" |findstr /i "install">nul || (
        echo %%~nG >> "%curpath%/names.txt"
        echo %%G >> "%curpath%/locations.txt"
    )
)
```

These shortcuts can be run instead of the EXEs to open the programs.

Answer (score 3):

One can use this one-liner:

```
 Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall | Get-ItemProperty |   ? { -not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.DisplayName) } |  Sort-Object -Property DisplayName | Select-Object -Property DisplayName, DisplayVersion, InstallLocation
```

Drawback: Not all application set the `InstallPath` property.

Answer (score 0):

I would not bother too much with the Uninstall key and just search the Program Files Directory.

This command gives you the name of each exe inside a program files subdir:

```
$ProgPath = $env:ProgramFiles, ${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}
dir $ProgPath -Directory | Select -Property Name, @{n="ExeFiles";e={ (dir $_.FullName -Filter *.exe -Recurse -Depth 1).Name -join ","}} | Where ExeFiles
```

This assumes it's a 64 bit OS otherwise drop the second path.

It's not perfect either since it might return the name of several exes but at least you don't have to worry about the peculiarities of a installer what registry items it writes etc.